# How to querry for an item that saved in an array?

Tags: wp-query

I know how to write querry args for WP_Query if it's a single key :
for example, if query posts with the metakey of 'type'--

```
$query_args['type'] = (array)$type;
```

Now, the problem is-- the item I want to querry is saved inside an array, this array is saved as a postmeta.
This is my array:

```
$details = array(
'user_id' => 0,
'type'   => '',
'amount' => 0,
);
```

I saved this array in wordpress postmeta:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'details', $details );
```

Now I want to query for posts that have the same metakey of 'type'. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenny, first of all, I think you may be better off using [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in you queries. However, there are a couple of hackish ways to do what you want to some extent.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1' );

$posts = $my_query->get_posts();
foreach ( $posts as &$post ) {
    // Get the details and unset if thy type is unwanted
    $details = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'details', true );
    if ( isset($details['type'])
        and $details['type'] != 'my_type ')
            unset( $post );
}
```

This will filter out posts that don't match a `type` of `my_type` in your `details` meta for the post.

However, note the performance issue - `get_post_meta` is called for each and every post, resulting in queries to the database. Ouch!

There is a more complex way to do this using a custom query to get all the meta at once like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT `post_id`, `meta_value`".
    " FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}".
    " WHERE `meta_key` = 'details'";

// Gather my meta
$metas = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
$details = array();
foreach  ( $metas as $meta ) $details[$meta->post_id] = unserialize($meta->meta_value);

$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1' );
$posts = $my_query->get_posts();

foreach ( $posts as &$post ) {
    // Filter the unwanted posts
    if ( isset($details[$post->ID]['type'])
        and $details[$post->ID]['type'] != 'my_type' )
            unset( $post );
}
```

This way you did only one extra query, by bringing the meta in in the beginning. A couple of things to note here:

- the basic principal is there - get all the posts, and filter them by `unset`ting
- $wpdb` should be in scope (if you're inside a function or method bring it in as a global)
- if you're going to play around with `" WHERE meta_key = 'details'";` make sure you escape what you feed into the query, otherwise it will be at risk of SQL injection
- wrap these into functions that will allow you to reuse them
- if you have a lot of posts in the query, this can get slow

Comment: Thanks for the idea of taxonomy, I think that could be the best way to handle my additional querry terms.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you have to save each element of your array as separate meta fields. As far as MySQL is concerned, your field is just a string of text, it doesn't have the ability to parse a PHP array.

Comment: Exactly. If you ever need to run a query on a field in that array, you'll need to split it out into its own meta value.  Otherwise, the array is serialized, and you can't use `WP_Query` to run a search.